# select sum from other table using group by

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two tables "invoices" and "invoices_account"

by query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(inv_created, '%Y') as 'year',
       COUNT(*) as 'total' 
FROM invoices as i 
WHERE inv_way = "OUT" 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(inv_created, '%Y')
```

I get amount of invoices per year like:

```
2011 | 80
2012 | 120
```

and so on.

What I need is to get summary of all entries from "invoices_account"."inv_total" by year in the first query. Relation is 1:1. That means that 80 invoices from 2011 have 80 rows in "invoices_account". And I need to have something like this

```
2011 | 80  | 1.000.000 €
2012 | 120 | 230.000.000 €
```

Answer (score 1):

Check **[INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(inv_created, '%Y') as 'year',
       COUNT(*) as 'total', 
       SUM(ia.inv_total) as money_total
FROM invoices as i 
JOIN invoices_account ia
  ON i.id = ia.id
WHERE inv_way = "OUT" 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(inv_created, '%Y')
```